# PHPDoc Create/Modified Date/Timestamp

Tags: phpdoc

What (if any) tag can be used to specify a create and/or last modified date for PHPDocumentor? For example:

```
@created 2013-01-01
@author John Doe
@updated 2013-01-06
```

This is primarily for file-level DocBlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I was curious if there was a standard for adding a date to a docblock and found this question.

For my particular use case, I do use code versions/versioning, but I am the solo developer on a project so only I look at my code, and as my data is date based, I like to use a `@introduced yyyy-mm-dd` tag in my docblocks. Nice and easy to understand and I haven't got to hunt down when a particular tag was released. My code is version controlled, so I can look at line/function history, so I never add/change the date.

```php
/**
 * A brief description of the function
 * 
 * @introduced 2020-06-24
 * @return array
 */
 public funcition hello()
 {
   return 'world';
 }
```